# docker: not found after mounting /var/run/docker.sock

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to use docker command inside container.
i use this command to mount /var/run/docker.sock and run container

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \                                                                  
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

but when i try to use docker inside container(gitlab-runner) i get an error

```
docker: not found
```

host:

```
srw-rw----  1 root docker    0 Mar 23 15:13 docker.sock
```

container:

```
0 srw-rw---- 1 root gitlab-runner    0 Mar 23 15:13 docker.sock
```

this worked fine, before i removed old container and created new one, and now i'm unable to run docker inside container. Please help.

Comment: In what path is docker installed? Can you invoke it using the full path?

Comment: It looks like GitLab runner uses `docker-machine` (which is installed inside this image) to autoscale the runner, and probably that's why you have to mount the `docker.sock` socket inside. However, I don't see that `docker` itself is installed in this image, and can't even find the appropriate revision where it was. Thus, it looks like `docker: not found` is the _expected_ result. If this worked for you previously, I suppose that you did some manual customization (like installing `docker` manually) in the running container and forgot about that, so container restart wiped all these changes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should differentiate between docker daemon and docker CLI. First one is a service, which actually performs all work - builds and runs containers. The second one is an executable, used to **send commands to daemon**.

Executable (docker CLI) is lightweight and uses `/var/run/docker.sock` to access daemon (by default, there are different transports actually).

When you start your container with `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` you actually **share your host's** docker daemon to docker CLI in container. Thus, you still need to install docker CLI inside container to make use of Docker, but you dont need to setup daemon inside (which is pretty complicated and requires priviledged mode).

**Conclusion**

Install docker CLI inside container, share socket and enjoy. But upon using host's docker daemon, you will probably be confused with bind mounting volumes because daemon doesn't see the container's internal file system.

Comment: I've listed the instructions to add the Docker CLI and bind mount the docker.sock here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55317547/1556338

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why mounting the docker.sock file didn't work immediately. It is because the gitlab-runner container did not have the docker.bin file.

```
docker cp /usr/bin/docker gitlab-runner:/usr/bin/docker
```

You can copy the docker.bin file with the above command instead of installing it. That with the docker.sock mount should make docker commands work in the gitlab-runnder container.