# Run command from one container to another

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I have two dockerized projects: one using NodeJS and the other one using Python

I want to trigger a Python script execution (on the container with the Python app) from the NodeJS app.

Basically the NodeJS app would run something like `exec('python3 script.py')`, but it's expected to be run on the Python app container.

How can I achieve this exact behavior? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to run python code inside your nodejs cotainer why don't you add python code to the nodejs container ?

Comment: It depends on what these apps are, what is their purpose, and what is the purpose of the script mentioned, but _in general_ what you want is a security breach and/or an architecture design flaw. Technically it is possible, but you should really avoid such relations between services.

Comment: @shotgunner because even when they share some resources, I want them to be separated

Comment: @DanilaKiver ok.. thanks for the info

Answer (score 10):

Docker containers are an implementation of the micro-service architecture. As such, they are expected to be fairly decoupled and communicate between themselves using TCP (HTTP typically). So your python container should expose some REST call (for instance).

There is a way to get around that, but it is not recommended since it opens up your docker daemon to anyone running inside the nodejs container. I'm listing it here since it can be useful during development.

1 - Install the Docker CLI
In your nodejs Dockerfile, add the following lines:

```
ENV DOCKER_VERSION=18.09.4
RUN curl -sfL -o docker.tgz "https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz" && \
  tar -xzf docker.tgz docker/docker --strip=1 --directory /usr/local/bin && \
  rm docker.tgz
```

This installs only the bare minimum CLI part of the full docker download.

2 - Bind mount the docker socket .
In your compose file, add the following:

```
services:
  mypython:
    container_name: mypython
    ...
  mynodejs:
    ...
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

3 - Call your python script .
From *inside* your nodejs container, you can now use the docker CLI.

```
# Log into your nodejs container first
docker exec -it mynodejs sh
# and execute some command in another container
docker exec mypython python3 script.py
```

The above is the easiest way to do it. You can also avoid installing the Docker CLI and use the [Docker API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/latest/) directly but it typically requires you to write multiple lines for what Docker CLI does in just one.

Comment: Remember if you do this, the Node process has **unrestricted root-level access over the host**.  Be really really careful with any path that starts from a network request and ends with running a Docker command: it's very easy to get your system rooted this way.

Comment: Thanks for the help... Anyways, when I try to run the python script, the docker cli is not installed for some reason :/

Comment: @JahirFiquitiva .  There was a formatting issue with the Dockefile line above. Copy it again. btw, you can debug Dockerfile by simply running the RUN instructions in an existing container and seeing what doesn't work.

Comment: The line for version should be `ENV DOCKER_VERSION=18.09.3`

Comment: the position of the tar's `--directory` aka -C flag is crucial. To resolve a possible issue (docker not found) in the command above, move the --directory command before `docker/docker` to have this: `ENV DOCKER_VERSION=18.09.4
RUN curl -sfL -o docker.tgz "https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-${DOCKER_VERSION}.tgz" && \
  tar -xzf docker.tgz --directory /usr/local/bin  docker/docker --strip=1 && \
  rm docker.tgz`