# Docker in Azure Container Instance (ACI): Unable to mount volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

In order to run Docker within another Docker container we need to launch a docker container with a volume mount -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock.

However, if one tries to do the same within ACI, there does not seem to be an option to do the same.

Did anyone try to install Docker daemon within an ACI or deployed StaticWebApp task on a ACI Linux Agent?

Ultimate goal is to run StaticWebApp CI task on an ACI Agent Pool.

Comment: You can refer to [Run command from one container to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317195/run-command-from-one-container-to-another/55317547#55317547), [Mounting of /var/run/docker.sock fails on Ubuntu target host
#](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.docker/issues/127) and [Mounting & using /var/run/docker.sock in a container not running as root](https://forums.docker.com/t/mounting-using-var-run-docker-sock-in-a-container-not-running-as-root/34390/9)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Does any of the above suggestions work in Azure Container Instances?